# What would be the average performance (big O notation) of this sorting algorithm

Tags: performance, math, random, time-complexity, big-o

Step 1: Chose two random elements of list

Step 2: If the first element is bigger than the second, swap them

Step 3: Repeat until sorted

Comment: Have you tried measuring it for an approximation? How would you guarantee that the sort finishes when it is possible that some element is never compared?

Comment: Seems like a tricky problem. There are N! permutations and exactly one of these sorts the list. Therefore, very roughly, you expect to need to try about N! random permutations before you found the correct one. But that's not exactly what you're doing here, you actually applying something like a random transposition at each step. I'm not sure how that affects the analysis.

Comment: @AndrewMorton here I did it up to n=250 with 100 repetitions each: https://i.imgur.com/ZexGztx.png

Comment: @owo Can you fit a curve to the data? Is a polynomial a good fit, or an exponential, or something else like n! ?

Comment: @AndrewMorton [here you go](https://i.imgur.com/ys83tRO.png) red is exponential, blue is power, which definitely fits better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to u/teraflop on reddit we now have the solution. In [this paper](http://www.hermann-gruber.com/pdf/fun07-final.pdf) the algorithm is called bozo-sort_opt and it is mentioned that the expected number of comparisons is O(n^3 log n). Sadly no proof is provided, but it'll do.